# Returning more than one variable in a C# 'get' statement

Tags: c#, get, return, vsto

In my Excel Add-In, I have created two task panes - with each ones visibility being from two different values, requiring both to be in a return statement, however it will only allow me to return one of the values.  These are 'taskPaneValue' and 'taskPaneValue2'.

How do I go about having both returned in the 'get' statement.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        taskPaneControl2 = new FileChooser();
        taskPaneValue2 = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl2, "File Chooser");
        taskPaneValue2.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);

        taskPaneValue2.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
        taskPaneValue2.Height = 600;
        taskPaneValue2.Width = 600;

        taskPaneValue2.DockPositionRestrict = Office.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;

        //These three lines of code start by initiating the TaskPane control (namely aLaCarteMenu()) 
        //It then goes on to set the name of the menu "A La Carte Menu" which appears on the top left of the window before stating its visibility.
        taskPaneControl1 = new aLaCarteMenu();
        taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl1, "A La Carte Menu");
        taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged +=

        //The following four lines of code are used to display the visiblity of the AddIn.
        //The docking position is set to float, with a resolution of 980x1920.  This is designed for a 1080p screen, however still working on changing it to fit screens dynamically.
        new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
        taskPaneValue.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
        taskPaneValue.Height = 980;
        taskPaneValue.Width = 1920;

        //This line of code sets the position to be restricted to what has been set above (floating).  This allows for the pane to be moved around the screen, as well as to be resized. 
        //This stops the pane from locking on to the right, left, top or bottom sections of the Excel Window.
        taskPaneValue.DockPositionRestrict = Office.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;


}

private void taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged(object sender,     System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon.toggleButton1.Checked = taskPaneValue.Visible;
        Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon.toggleButton2.Checked = taskPaneValue2.Visible;

    }

    public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane TaskPane
    {
        get
        {
            return taskPaneValue2;
        }

    }
```

The final 'get' statement is the one I wish to return both variables.

Comment: Have you considered a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) or creating a type to hold both values which you could create and return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Tuple or create a class that has all the properties you are looking for and make that the return type of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a method with out parameter modifier, if it'still possible to you. Please, check the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx